# Can I declare a type [[nodiscard]] with 'using'?

Tags: c++, c++17, nodiscard

You can declare a class with the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute. It may be useful when you know from the semantics of this class that whenever it's returned from a function, it must be used for something. I have exactly this case, and it would be very convenient to tag the class with `[[nodiscard]]` instead of each individual function that returns it. However, there's one complication. This is the type that I need to make `[[nodiscard]]`:

```
using ConnectionStruct = std::pair<std::shared_ptr<CMutex>, std::shared_ptr<SignalFunction>>;
```

Is there a syntax to mark my `ConnectionStruct` as `[[nodiscard]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[nodiscard]]` cannot be applied to aliases. [Only to:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.attr.nodiscard)

> The attribute-token nodiscard may be applied to the declarator-id in a **function declaration** or to the declaration of a **class or enumeration**.

Emphasis added.